# RangeError [ERR_CHILD_PROCESS_STDIO_MAXBUFFER]:stdout maxBuffer length exceeded

Tags: node.js, meteor, stdout, spawn

I get this error [image]

when running this block of code,

```
 reasoner = new Reasoner({
    type: 'local', 
    folder: 'csp_files' 
 });

 console.log("solving Model");
 reasoner.solve(Model, (err, stdout, stderr, isSatisfiable) => {
    console.log("isSatisfiable");
    console.log(isSatisfiable);
    if (err) {
        // manage error
        console.log("model error");
        future_response.return("model error");
    } else {
        // manage solution
        console.log(stdout);
        console.log(isSatisfiable);
        future_response.return(stdout);
    }
 });
 console.log("Model solved");
 return future_response.wait();
```

from what I have read I should find a way to rewrite the `stdout` to support bigger buffer length, could someone please advice how I could do it? I believe that the library `spawn` is what I should use, right?
I use node version 12.16.1 and meteor

Answer (score 4):

You need to use and set the **maxBuffer** option when using child_process.exec. From the :
[documentation](https://www.hacksparrow.com/nodejs/difference-between-spawn-and-exec-of-node-js-child-rocess.html)

It is - the differences between spawn() and exec() of Node's child_process. Use spawn() when you want the child process to return huge binary data to Node, use exec() when you want the child process to return simple status messages.